# Excel Chart Color - Create charts with conditional formatting on "text value"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts, data-visualization

I have a data set of Companies/Products with their performances for every quarter. 
I am creating a lot of graph to display the various performance.

**Problem:** 
In order to be coherent, I'd like

1. to always use the same color for each company  (Company A = Blue,
   Company B = Red, Company C = Yellow...)
2. to have the legend in the right order based on performance in the last quarter(Company D, top performer = 1st in the legend for example).

**Solution:** 
If I sort the data using the Alphabetical order, it's working properly for the company color but the legend is also in alphabetical order and not depending on the performance.

If I sort the data using the performance, the companies have different colors...

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrbYN.png)

I read some tutorial about conditional formatting Graph, but it's depending on a number/value and not attributing a color to a specific "text".

Thank you in advance for your help/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the colour of the lines:

```
Single click on the line to select the line. Dots appear on it.

Right click. Select "Format data series" from the box that pops up.

You can change colour, line weight, etc., there.
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
 
I know how to do it "one by one" 
The only problem is that I have 8 companies and multiple graphs... 
So 8*xx the manipulation...